# data-cacheval jquery mobile issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hello people of the Stack Overflow,

I am in need of your help. I am having a difficult time with getting the data-cacheval in a jquery mobile checkbox using javascript. How would get the result of data-cacheval being true or false using javascript. The value of checked true does not change during click only the data-cacheval, so I need to detect the change in javascript.

`<label for="autoRefresh" class="ui-btn  ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-right ui-checkbox-on ui-first-child ui-last-child">Auto-Refresh</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="autoRefresh" id="autoRefresh" checked="true" data-cacheval="true">`

data-cacheval="true" data-cacheval="false" toggles so I need to read the data-cacheval in javascript not the checked.

checked="true" always remains the same

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you dont need `data-cacheval`. You need to listen to `change` event and then retrieve `.prop("checked")` of the checkbox. e.g. `$("#autoRefresh").on("change", function () { var value = $(this).prop("checked"); console.log(value); });`

Comment: ...checked="true" always remains the same. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you:

```
$("#myCheckbox").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found work a around. Check this out, class ui-checkbox-on changes from ui-checkbox-on to ui-checkbox-off. I just found a change in the labels class of ui-checkbox-on to or from ui-checkbox-off.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('data-cacheval','true');
```

or

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('data-cacheval','false')
```

if you really want to change that attribute.